# Oracle relative to which BPP = EXP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, oracles, relativization

An oracle construction relative to which BPP = EXP is usually attributed to Heller (Mathematical System Theory Vol. 17, 1984). Unfortunately I don't have the paper available in my library. Could someone explain how it goes? If it is easier to give an oracle where NP = EXP that would fine already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would write this as a comment, but there was a limitation on the number of characters. So I'll put it here.

The paper title is "[Relativized Polynomial Hierarchies Extending Two Levels](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01744434)." When you do not have access to an article, your best bet is to search for books/articles that reference your indented paper. The best place, IMO, is [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=4173642586326142804&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=2000&hl=en) and [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Relativized%20polynomial%20hierarchies%20extending%20two%20levels%22&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbo=u&tbs=bks:1&gws_rd=ssl).

The Complexity Zoo attributes the proof that "There exist oracles relative to which EXP = NP = ZPP" to this paper. Yet this is *incomplete*, since other references cite the following papers as well [off-topic: I updated Zoo to cover the new references as well]:

1. Heller, H. 1984. On relativized polynomial and exponential computations. SIAM J. Comput. 13, 4 (Nov. 1984), 717-725. DOI= http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0213045

   Heller, H. 1986. On relativized exponential and probabilistic complexity classes. Inf. Control 71, 3 (Dec. 1986), 231-243. DOI= http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958(86)80012-2

There's also the following paper:

- Kurtz, S. A. 1985. Sparse sets in NP-P: relativizations. SIAM J. Comput. 14, 1 (Feb. 1985), 113-119. DOI= http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0214008

cited by several references as having influence on the relativized ZPP = EXP result (see for instance "[Comparing Notions of Full Derandomization](https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings-article/ccc/2001/10530028/12OmNBhpRZw)" by Lance Fortnow).

Specially, while the paper you cited only proves the existence of an oracle $B$ such that

${(\Sigma _1^p)^B} \subset {(\Sigma _2^p)^B} = (\Pi _2^B)$,

The paper #1 above continues by proving:

${(\Sigma _2^p)^B} = (\Pi _2^B) = \mathbf{EXP}^B = \mathbf{NEXP}^B$

and paper #2 above completes it by showing the relations between relatizied **EXP** and (if I'm not mistaken) **RP**.

Joining forces, the relativized **BPP** = **NEXP** is deduced.

PS: Please provide me with an email address of yours. I want to send you some docs.

Comment: The ZPP entry of the <a ref="http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo">complexity zoo</a> points to Heller's paper (the one you link to) as giving an oracle relative to which ZPP = EXP (and hence BPP = EXP too). I've seen other references to this paper for the same claim.

Comment: There's a more direct route. It turns out that the SIAMJC paper above (which I didn't know of and which is available in my library) contains an oracle construction relative to which NP = EXP (Theorem 6 in that paper). The proof is simple enough that I see how to extend it to an oracle relative to which BPP = EXP. So this answers my question.

Comment: @Joshua: Sure thing! @slimton: I was justifying how the paper cited by you influenced the BPP = EXP, though as you pointed, the definite result appeared in the SIAMJC paper.