# Relativized world in which P ≠ NP = coNP

Tags: complexity-classes, oracles, relativization

Do we know of an oracle relative to which P ≠ NP but NP = coNP?

Comment: Sure. There are even oracles $A$ such that $\mathrm{EXP}^A=\mathrm{NP}^A$; this implies $\mathrm{NP}^A=\mathrm{coNP}^A$ as $\mathrm{EXP}^A$ is closed under complement, and $\mathrm P^A\ne\mathrm{NP}^A$ on pain of contradicting the relativized time-hierarchy theorem. One such oracle (further satisfying $\mathrm{EXP}^A=\mathrm{ZPP}^A$) is referenced in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1545; another (satisfying $\mathrm{EXP}^A=\mathrm{NP}^A=\oplus\mathrm P^A=\mathrm{ZPP}^A$ and $\mathrm{Mod_3P}^A=\mathrm P^A$) is referenced in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/38765.

Comment: This also sounds like a good resource: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/12366

Comment: @EmilJeřábek write these comments as answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some oracles of this sort were given in other answers on this site:

- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1545 gives references to an oracle $A$ such that $\mathrm{EXP}^A=\mathrm{NP}^A=\mathrm{ZPP}^A$.
- https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/38765 gives a reference to an oracle $A$ such that $\mathrm{EXP}^A=\oplus\mathrm P^A=\mathrm{NP}^A=\mathrm{ZPP}^A$ and $\oplus_3\mathrm P^A=\mathrm P^A$.

Note that $\mathrm{EXP}^A=\mathrm{NP}^A$ implies $\mathrm{NP}^A=\mathrm{coNP}^A$ and $\mathrm P^A\ne\mathrm{NP}^A$ by the relativized time-hierarchy theorem.

Furthemore, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/12366 gives a reference to a paper that lists many oracle separations between the most common classes.